# Как сделать реплику sqlite3, с учетом того, что бд работает в контейнере докер под джанго

Tags: django, docker, sqlite3, docker-compose, резервное-копирование

У меня есть проект, в нем на вдс работает контейнер с Джанго в котором бд sqlite3, мне нужно любым способом делать реплику этой бд (вручную, т.е. только когда мне нужно). Возможно по какому-то апи отдавать бд файлом, или выгружать из докера на машину и потом вручную сбрасывать на свой комп. Любой способ. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

долучилось решить командой:

docker cp <container_name>:<пусть к проекту> <путь куда копируем на текущем сервере>

и после вручную забрал файл с Помощью ftp